# Browser-based C and Objective-C tutorials

Tags: objective-c, c

I've seen some great in-browser tutorials and/or practice exercises in other languages.  To name a few:

Ruby: Tryruby.org
JS: Codeacademy.com
Rails: railsforzombies.com

I've also seen great Java algorithm challenges at codingbat.com.

I haven't found anything similar for learning C, or Objective-C (which is my real goal).  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go ahead with http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/objc.pdf
for Objective-C. It works great on my browser- opens up the pdf.

Comment: best material to learn objective-C is at Apple so you should follow the link.

Comment: He's looking for an interactive tutorial, so you link the PDF version of a webpage? I would at least do http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html instead.

Comment: Yes -- "in-browser"... as in "you ask me a question, and I write code.. and you tell me if it's the right solution... just like the format of the four sites I mentioned.